# Video Player not work - MVC 5 - View

Tags: view, asp.net-mvc-5, html5-video, memorystream

I have in my view Video Play normal functioning.

The problem is marked in red:

[image]

Where is the blue ball, he does not go and does not return.

Only it is running until the end of the video.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Media(int id)
{
    string fn = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/01.mp4");
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fn));
    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fn)));
}
```

**View:**

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="@Url.Action("Media","Account",new { id = 3 })" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Pause works, moving video time does not work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Might not be an exact duplicate, but this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801594/seeking-functionality-on-mp4-video-in-html5-is-not-working

Comment: Hello @David, it seems that has to do with byte range requests